# How to fix external hard drive sectors?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, external-hard-drive, bad-sectors

Whenever I insert my external hard drive into my laptop I get an error message:
`'there is a problem with this drive'`. I have used EaseUS partition manager and identified that the first sector is faulty. I have tried using third party apps and CHKDSK, both which stopped part way through and prompted the message:

```
The type of the file system is exFAT.
Volume Serial Number is 8285-B506
A media error has been detected. Bad sectors may be present on the volume.
The volume will be checked for bad sectors.
```

This message didn't appear when I ran CHKDSK the first time using the GUI(graphical user interface), when the original message popped up. However, an error came up saying it couldn't repair the drive. When I ran it in cmd(command line) as administrator the error message above came up and then it returned to the cmd input line without any further message. After this I ran the partition manager again and the same sector is faulty. What should I do?

Note: I am new to stack exchange and would love any tips on improving my question. Thanks.

Comment: Did you use chkdsk /R d:  ?  This will probably take hours.  Replace d: with the drive letter of your external hdd.

Comment: @cybernard I ran the command chkdsk e: /f /r /x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to fix external hard drive sectors?

First you can't fix a bad sector.

chkdsk /r c: (or whatever drive letter) will only hide the bad sector so your OS won't freak out.

Your hard drive is supposed to have SMART on it, and it is supposed to swap a bad sector out for a spare sector hiding the bad sector.  However, on most hard drives this is simply wishful thinking as in most cases I encountered it just does not work.  Sure there are a limited number of spares, but I have seen plenty of drives with spares fail to reallocate bad sectors.

There are software packages like spinrite,victoria (hdd.by), or dban which you can try to beat the bad sector into submission by writing over it dozens or hundreds of times, but this usually fails and wastes a lot of time.

Replacing the drive is the only option to truly get rid of the bad sectors, everything else just hides them.

It is possible for a bad sector to occur in a critical area of the file system such as in FAT16/32 if the bad sector occurs with the FAT the drive will be unusable without tricks. For example if a bad sector did occur within the FAT, one could create a partition starting a 1gb instead of the normal sector 64. You would lose 1gb of capacity, but the drive would be usable.

Comment: Will formatting fix it or not?

Comment: Formatting will not fix it, but just like chkdsk /R it will mark the sector as bad and the OS will not attempt to use it.  If you do a quick format, then it may clear the bad sectors, and the OS will trip over them again.  NTFS retains the bad sector list, but FAT16/32 does not.  Not sure about exFAT, but since it is FAT based it might.